# How to handle a changing input shape on an embedding layer

Tags: python, keras, embedding

I am trying out a recommendation problem with keras
my model is as follows

```
def build_model(n_users, n_movies, n_factors, min_rating, max_rating):
   user = Input(shape=(1,))
   u = EmbeddingLayer(n_users, n_factors)(user)
   movie = Input(shape=(1,))
   m = EmbeddingLayer(n_movies, n_factors)(movie)
   x = Concatenate()([u, m])
   x = Dropout(0.05)(x)
   x = Dense(10, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
   x = Activation('relu')(x)
   x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
   x = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
   x = Activation('sigmoid')(x)
   x = Lambda(lambda x: x * (max_rating - min_rating) + min_rating)(x)
   model = Model(inputs=[user, movie], outputs=x)
   opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
   model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt)
   return model
```

Is there anyway to retrain the model when the number of users change over time with out starting from scratch as the embedding layer would not work if my understanding of embedding is right. I would have to retrain the model from scratch when the number of users or movies would change, is there any way to preserve the weights learned on the dense layers.